# Facebook Messenger Bot - button to upload image

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm trying to get my bot ask the user for file attachment or images. Is there a way I can call the image attachment or file attachment command from a facebook messenger button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible yet with FB Messenger. The best way to deal with this scenario just asks the user attach a file manually (by clicking on the attachment button on the messenger). You can then create a command to catch the attachment and parse.

- Step 1: Code the bot to ask "Please upload your attachment".
- Step 2: User clicks on attachment button, attach file
- Step 3: Code the Bot to catch the file and parse

If any changes to the Messenger that supports this, I'll update this post.